# Oracle. Sql. Выборка данных за период даты и в диапазоне времени

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется столбец набор данных - дата со временем (type DATE)
необходимо получить все значения находящиеся в заданном периоде дат и диапазоне времени:
к примеру выбрать все записи с 14:25 до 19:30 в разные дни

```
Select * 
from Dates dt
where dt.date_time > to_date('2024-01-01 06:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
and dt.date_time < to_date('2024-01-11 05:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')

and tr.date_time - trunc(tr.date_time) > to_date('14:25','hh24:mi')
and tr.date_time - trunc(tr.date_time) < to_date('19:30','hh24:mi')

-- [1]: ORA-00932: несовместимые типы данных: ожидается NUMBER, получено DATE
```

Подскажите как правильно добавить условие для выборки диапазона времени, не хочется в несколько уровней строить запрос

Comment: *ORA-00932* Вы пытаетесь вычитать даты. Используйте `.. and TO_CHAR(tr.date_time, 'fxHH24MI') BETWEEN '1425' AND '1930'`

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли, в эту сторону не думал   -  ` and to_char(tr.date_time,'fxhh24:MI:ss') between '17:00:00' and '23:30:00' `

Comment: А зачем лишние разделители-то? чтобы сервер больше работал, что ли?

Answer (score 0):

Вычитать даты - это правильное решение, позволяющее серверу избежать затратных преобразований из даты в строку (да ещё с учётом текущей локали!).

Ваше условие

```
tr.date_time - trunc(tr.date_time) > to_date('14:25','hh24:mi')
and tr.date_time - trunc(tr.date_time) < to_date('19:30','hh24:mi')
```

нужно записать как

```
(tr.date_time - trunc(tr.date_time))*24*60 between 14*60+25 and 19*60+30
```